# How to Allow Image to Scale Past the Container, Or Fill the Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a system that allows the user to hover over an image and it will enlarge for better visibility.

Currently on hover, the image does enlarge as expected, but it is contained within the div. However, I cannot make the div overflow visible because it is core to the collapsible. I would like the image to overflow the container when enlarged.

```js
        document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible").forEach((coll) => {
          coll.addEventListener("click", () => {
            coll.classList.toggle("active");

            const content = coll.nextElementSibling;

            if (content.style.maxHeight) {
              content.style.maxHeight = null;
              // Add this:
              content.style.borderWidth = 0;
            } else {
              content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
              // And this:
              content.style.borderWidth = "1px";
            }
          });
        });
```

```css
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition:
  border 0.2s ease-out,
  max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0px solid #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.collapsible {
  background-color: white;
  color: #021032;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

.photo {

  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

 .photo:hover{
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(5);
  -ms-transform: scale(5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(5);
  overflow: visible;

}
```

```html
        <button type="button" class="collapsible"> Consult Logs <div class="icon"><div></button>

        <div class="content">
          <div class="column">
            <p>Ensure the disc strength is not at “0”.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <img src="../images/discStrength.png" alt="Picture of Logs" class="photo" onclick="enlarge()">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: try making the image position absolute when hovering - you might need to adjust positioning at first to match the original positioning

Comment: I see, you're a legend. The hovering thing isn't really working out. Is there a way to make it enlarge on click?

Comment: you would need to set an [onclick function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) and inside of that [call the animation on that object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_animation.asp)

Comment: put your box around the image in relative position, make it fit the space you want, put the image in position absolute in the middle of the box. You can then use `transform: scale(1.5);` when hovering on your image.